# サイトが表示されません。

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, postgresql, ffmpeg

https://github.com/blobmon/simplechan

上の掲示板をネット上に設置したのですが、ホーム画面は表示されるのですが、そこからクリックをして入ったら本来表示されるべきものが表示されません。クリックしたらこんなものが出てきます。

```
psycopg2.OperationalError
OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "simplech_role"
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/root/simplechan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/root/simplechan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/root/simplechan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/root/simplechan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/root/simplechan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/root/simplechan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/root/simplechan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/root/simplechan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/root/simplechan/app/app/__init__.py", line 91, in mod_logs
handler = Handler()
File "/root/simplechan/app/app/handler.py", line 26, in __init__
self.con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='{}' user='{}'".format(app.config['DB_NAME'], app.config['DB_ROLE']) )
File "/root/simplechan/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

OperationalError: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "simplech_role"

The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error. 

To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object

Brought to you by DON'T PANIC, your friendly Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
```

と表示されます。何が原因でこういう風になったのでしょうか？
あと、サイトにもある通り"ffmpeg"をインストールしようと、activateしながら

```
pip install ffmpeg
```

と入力したら

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement subprocess (from ffmpeg) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for subprocess (from ffmpeg)
```

と赤文字で表示されました。どうやったら、インストールできますか？

あと、pythonを最後に実行したらこのように表示されます。

```
(venv) root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~/simplechan/app# python runserver.py
/root/simplechan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/root/simplechan/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 931-992-838
```

Comment: リンク先に「Finally, rename appconfig_template.cfg to appconfig.cfg and update proper UPLOAD_PATH, DB_NAME, DB_ROLE, and hash values as required.」とありますが、これはやってあるのでしょうか?

Comment: ｛rename appconfig_template.cfg to appconfig.cfg ｝この名前は変えましたがほかはどうやっていいのかわからないのでやっていません。あと、質問にpython実行時のエラーを加えておいたのでそれもお願いします！！

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/131445

Comment: マルチポスト　https://m.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/q12191860462

Answer (score 1):

## データベースのセットアップは正常に行えていますか?

エラーメッセージから察するにデータベースの認証に失敗しているようですが,ロールとデータベースは正常に作成しましたか?

データベースにログイン出来るか確かめて下さい.

パスワードを指定していないため,localhostを信頼する設定になっているかも調べる必要があると思います.

[python - connect to a DB using psycopg2 without password - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192134/connect-to-a-db-using-psycopg2-without-password)

## ffmpegのインストールはpipで行うものではありません

[ffmpeg · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg/)は全く意味のないダミーパッケージのようです.

普通ffmpegのような汎用的なプログラムは言語のパッケージマネージャでインストールするものではありません.

明らかにコマンドラインから呼んでますし.
[simplechan/blobHandler.py at master · blobmon/simplechan](https://github.com/blobmon/simplechan/blob/master/app/app/blobHandler.py#L122)

Ubuntuにはaptがあるので,

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

とかで入るのではないでしょうか.

## 解決したようなので追記

コメントでのやり取りで解決したので追記します.

やはりパスワードを指定していないため,localhostを信頼する設定にする必要があったようですね.
原因がはっきりしたため,｢信頼する設定｣などというふわっとした表現ではなく,具体的に手順をリンク先に頼らずに明記しておきます.

`/etc/postgresql-9.6/pg_hba.conf`を開きます.
PostgreSQLのバージョンは各自のものに置き換えてください.

`ADDRESS`が`127.0.0.1/32`になっている行の`METHOD`を`trust`に変更する必要があります.
これでローカルからの接続ではパスワードが不要になります.

Gentooなどではこの値はデフォルトで`trust`なのですが,Debian系では`md5`となっているようです.

Comment: "psql -U user_name -d database_name -h 127.0.0.1 -W" と入力すれば、データベースに入れるのですが、これではだめでしょうか？ロールのパスワードはもう設定してあります。

Comment: エラーメッセージを見る限りロールの名前はsimplech_roleのようですが,これでログインできますか?またソースを見る限りパスワードは送信していないので,設定するとダメでパスワード無しのログインを要求しているように読めます.公式ドキュメントには`psql -d simplech_db -U simplech_role`でログインさせていますね.

Comment: "simplech_role"で"psql -U user_name -d database_name -h 127.0.0.1 -W" と入力すれば入れますが、psql -d simplech_db -U simplech_role　では"psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "simplech_role""と表示されます。なぜできないのでしょうか？手順通りにやったのですが、、

Comment: はい。わかりました。以後気をつけます。

Comment: あと、サイトの最後にある通りpythonを実行したら以下の通りにエラーが表示されます。ここには入りきらないので質問に加えます。なるべく早く解決したいのでお願いします！！

Comment: そもそもroleが作られているか怪しいのでpsqlのconsoleで\duを実行してロールの存在を確認してみましょう.user_nameでアクセスしたいならそれに合わせてappconfigの内容とuser_nameの認証方法を変える必要があります.create_table_queryを実行するときはどのロールとデータベースでログインしましたか?

Comment: \duを入力したら｛ simplech_role | Superuser, Create DB                                       | {}
｝と表示されます。ちゃんと作られていますよね？{psql -d simplech_db -U simplech_role}　と入力しても入れませんでした。{psql -U user_name -d database_name -h 127.0.0.1 -W} なら入れます。そこからやりました。

Comment: あと、appconfigの内容とuser_nameの認証方法を変えるのはどうやってやるんですか？appconfigの中を見ましたが、ちゃんとデータベースとロールはありました。

Comment: 最初の回答で述べた通りパスワードを要求しないログインを許可する必要があります. https://www.postgresql.jp/document/9.4/html/auth-pg-hba-conf.html を参考にしてlocalhostがtrustになっているか確認してみてください.それでもpsqlでのログインが成功しない場合pa_hda.confの内容を貼り付けてください.インターネットに公開されているサーバでこの作業を行なった場合クラッキングされる可能性があるのでこの作業はローカルのPCで行ってください.

Comment: appconfigの内容を変更するというのはあなたが他のユーザでログインさせることを望む場合です.エラーメッセージとプログラムからプログラムはsimplech_roleを使ってパスワード無しでログインしようとして失敗しているようだとわかります.

Comment: できません。# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

Comment: # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
このように編修したのですが駄目でした。あと、ローカルのPCで行うと書いてありますがどのように行うんですか？私はPuTTyで行っているのですが。

Comment: クラッキングされる可能性があるというのは私の勘違いでした.ローカルホストからのみの場合は危険性はないですね.気にしないでください.設定ファイルの貼り付けに改行がないのでコメントとの違いがわかりにくいのですが,認証方式にmd5と書かれていますね.これはパスワードの入力を要求する方式なのでtrustに書き換えてください.設定行のコメントアウトは外してください.設定後PostgreSQLは再起動してください(本当に再起動が必要かは知らない).

Comment: 追記,「設定行のコメントアウトは外してください」というのは設定のコメントアウトを外して設定を有効化させるという意味で説明のコメントアウトを外すという意味ではないです

Comment: ありがとうございます！！できました！！